# что нужно сделать, чтоб попасть на сайт не по его домену, по ip адресу?

Tags: веб-программирование, ip, домен

то есть, указываем в адресной строке не домен сайта, а ip сервера и попадаем на сайт. вот так вот http://95.213.195.82

Comment: Эм, ну, указываете в адресной строке ip сервера и попадаете на сайт, вот и всё. (Если сайт на сервере вообще запущен, разумеется)

Comment: А для каких целей ? Это поможет ответить на ваш вопрос

Comment: пробовал. для примера, есть сайт http://mmabot.ru/, вот ip сервера 31.220.16.183, и по переходу на http://31.220.16.183 ничего не получатся

Comment: На этом IP-адресе сотни других сайтов, и без указания конкретного домена сервер не сможет определить, какой именно сайт надо показать

Comment: к гуглу например нормально всё посылает 216.58.209.163

Comment: @Арина, разместить тестовую версию сайта для правок и экспериментов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого у сайта должен быть выделенный IP. Например, на VPS или dedicated.
На обычных shared-хостингах это не получится, там на одном IP висят сотни сайтов.

Comment: ну можно же наверное как-то добавить порт и добиться уникальности, нет?

Comment: @pavel зависит от конкретного сервера

Comment: а обращаться с этим вопросом к поставщику хостинга?

Comment: IP-адрес - не бесплатная штука. Либо попросят отдельных денег, либо стоимость входит в тариф. Как бы то ни было - да, обращаться к хостеру.

Comment: @АндрейПилюгин спасибо большое!